# Does Mark Hadley's Theory make Sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, unified-theories

I just recently discovered [this theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9706018). It claims to derive quantum mechanics from general relativity. I found this interesting and perhaps promising, but I'm afraid I don't have enough expertise to say with confidence that this theory is worth anything.

Comment: Hadley's proposition is that the presence of closed timelike curves (time loops) in a space-time causes counterfactual dependencies whose appropriate formal representation is that of quantum mechanics. It does indeed seem that no one has ever bothered to scrutinize the argument in sufficient detail, that they could lay out for a third party, whether it is valid or invalid. As for peer review, the reviewers may have let it through on the grounds that it was interesting and not obviously wrong.